# how to using partial refund in Cybersource Simple Order API

Tags: c#, cybersource

The refund(credit) could be found at Table 21 in page 77.

http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/CC_Svcs_SO_API/Credit_Cards_SO_API.pdf#page=76&zoom=100,0,100

Had anyone experience, using cybersource partial  refund.

How to know the refund api domain?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

In general partial refunds do work. Just pass in the amount that you wish to refund with your refund request. With multiple partial refunds you cannot go over the original settlement amount with the default configuration.

The domain of the API is the same for all CyberSource SOAP requests.
Test: https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor
Production: https://ics2wsa.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor
For more information on connecting to CyberSource with C# see [here](https://www.cybersource.com/developers/integration_methods/simple_order_and_soap_toolkit_api/dot_net_client_library/) for the .Net pre-built client and [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/SOAP_Toolkits/SOAP_toolkits.pdf) to build your own client.

Comment: Hi Will, My parameter ccCreditService_captureRequestID is wrong, Do you know how to get this parameter?

Comment: That parameter comes from the result of a capture API request. Using that for a refund request is called a follow on refund request and requires the capture to happen first. If you want to do a stand alone refund you don't pass that parameter but  you do have to pass the credit card fields.